# Делегаты для QComboBox - как при изменении одного списка обновлять другой?

Tags: c++, qt, gui

Есть делегат `class ComboBoxDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate`, используется для `QTableView`, как отловить изменение текущего элемента в QComboBox? 
Пробовал `commitData(QWidget*)` у `itemDelegateForColumn()` и `itemChanged(QStandardItem*)` у модели.
`setModelData()` срабатывает уже при выходе из режима редактирования, а мне нужно отслеживать на лету изменение текущего элемента списка, чтобы генерировать новый список элементов для другого делегата-комбобокса в другой колонке (и только для текущей строки).

Answer (score 1):

Можно отслеживать текущий элемент в выпадающем списке путём пересылки сигнала [`currentIndexChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) класса [`QComboBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html) на уровень класса `ComboBoxDelegate`. Пересылку сигнала необходимо производить в методе [`createEditor`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#createEditor) класса делегата. Пример реализации:

```cpp
class ComboBoxDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

    ...

public:
    QWidget* ComboBoxDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
      const QStyleOptionViewItem &/* option */,
      const QModelIndex &/* index */) const
    {
        QComboBox* editor = new QComboBox(parent);
        editor->addItem(...);
        editor->addItem(...);
        ...

        // "Перебрасываем" сигнал на уровень класса.
        connect(editor, SINGAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), SINGAL(currentIndexChanged(int));

        return editor;
    }

signals:
    void currentIndexChanged(int index);

    ...

}
```

Таким образом, в коде, который создаёт экземпляры класса `ComboBoxDelegate`, можно перехватывать сигнал изменения текущего элемента.

Нечто подобное я уже описывал [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486399/200169).