# QComboBox delegate

Tags: c++, qt

Пишу редактор csv-файла определенного формата, используя модель-представление-делегат(`QAbstractTableModel`-`QTableView`-`QStyledItemDelegate`).

Данные во втором столбце состоят из двух пунктов(items) комбобокса - "ФизЛицо" и "ЮрЛицо". В зависимости от выбранного значения во втором столбце, необходимо чтобы комбобокс в ячейке третьего столбца имел пункты, связанные только c "ФизЛицо" или только с "ЮрЛицо", т.к. значения по ним отличаются. То есть во всей таблице "ФизЛицо" и "ЮрЛицо" идут вперемежку. Как это реализовать?

Comment: А откуда вы берете значения третьего столбца (из бд?) ? И если не из бд - то где у вас в модели прописанна зависимость значений третьего от второго?

Comment: Есть два файла со списками ФизЛиц и ЮрЛиц, эти списки загружаются в QStringList при входе в программу.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ещё один вариант решения этой задачи. Он гораздо компактнее и, скорее всего, соответствует вашим требованиям.

В классе делегата для третьего столбца [`QTableView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html), наследованном от [`QStyledItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html), в методе [`createEditor`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#createEditor) при создании экземпляра класса [`QComboBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html) с помощью аргумента типа [`QModelIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html) можно обратиться к данным второго столбца. Пример реализации:

```cpp
// Класс делегата для третьего столбца.
class ThirdColumnStyledItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

    ...

public:
    QWidget* ThirdColumnStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
      const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
      const QModelIndex& index) const
    {
        QComboBox* editor = new QComboBox(parent);

        // Получаем данные второго столбца через индекс модели.
        QString secondRowData = index.model()->index(index.row(), 1).data().toString();
        if(secondRowData  == tr("ФизЛицо"))
        {
            editor->addItem(...);
            editor->addItem(...);
            ...
        }
        else if(secondRowData == tr("ЮрЛицо"))
        {
            editor->addItem(...);
            editor->addItem(...);
            ...
        }

        return editor;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю вам следующий вариант решения задачи:

1. В классе делегата для второго столбца [`QTableView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html), наследованном от [`QStyledItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html), в методе [`createEditor`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#createEditor) при создании экземпляра класса [`QComboBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html) необходимо "перебросить" сигнал изменения выбранного элемента [`currentIndexChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) во внешнюю среду. Пример реализации:

```cpp
// Класс делегата для второго столбца.
class SecondColumnStyledItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

    ...

public:
    QWidget* SecondColumnStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
      const QStyleOptionViewItem &/* option */,
      const QModelIndex &/* index */) const
    {
        QComboBox* editor = new QComboBox(parent);
        editor->addItem(tr("ФизЛицо"));
        editor->addItem(tr("ЮрЛицо"));

        // "Перебрасываем" сигнал на уровень класса.
        connect(editor, SINGAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), SINGAL(currentIndexChanged(int));

        return editor;
    }

signals:
    void currentIndexChanged(int index);

    ...

}
```

2. В классе делегата для третьего столбца [`QTableView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html), наследованном от [`QStyledItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html), необходимо реализовать слот для "приёма" сигналов [`currentIndexChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) класса из предыдущего пункта. В этом слоте необходимо сохранить номер выбранного элемента во втором столбце. В дальнейшем этот номер следует использовать в методе [`createEditor`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#createEditor) класса при создании экземпляра класса [`QComboBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html) для установки в нём необходимых элементов. Пример реализации:

```cpp
// Класс делегата для третьего столбца.
class ThirdColumnStyledItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

    ...

public:
    QWidget* ThirdColumnStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
      const QStyleOptionViewItem &/* option */,
      const QModelIndex &/* index */) const
    {
        QComboBox* editor = new QComboBox(parent);
        switch(currentIndex)
        {
        // Пункты для "ФизЛицо".
        case 0:
        {
            editor->addItem(...);
            editor->addItem(...);
            ...
        }
        // Пункты для "ЮрЛицо".
        case 1:
        {
            editor->addItem(...);
            editor->addItem(...);
            ...
        }
        }

        return editor;
    }

public slot:
    void saveCurrentIndex(int index)
    {
         currentIndex = index;
    }

private:
    int currentIndex;

    ...
}
```

3. В том месте, где создаются экземпляры классов делегатов второго и третьего столбца, соединить сигнал [`currentIndexChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) первого класса со слотом `saveCurrentIndex` второго класса. Пример реализации:

```cpp
...

QTableView* tableView = new QTableView;

SecondColumnStyledItemDelegate* secondColumnStyledItemDelegate =
  new SecondColumnStyledItemDelegate(tableView);
tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, secondColumnStyledItemDelegate);

ThirdColumnStyledItemDelegate* thirdColumnStyledItemDelegate =
  new ThirdColumnStyledItemDelegate(tableView);
tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(2, thirdColumnStyledItemDelegate);

connect(secondRowStyledItemDelegate, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),
        thirdRowStyledItemDelegate, SLOT(saveCurrentIndex(int)));

...
```

Comment: При использовании вашего варианта реализации выходит, что при изменении пункта например во второй строке на ФизЛицо, в любой другой строке в третьем столбце в пунктах комбобокса будут отображаться данные, принадлежащие к ФизЛицам, не зависимо, какой пункт выбран во втором столбце этой же самой строки - то есть этот вариант не является правильным решением.

Comment: [Ниже](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486575/200169) я добавил ещё один вариант решения этой задачи, учитывающий ваше замечание.